# Difference between brace initialization and copy initialization a dynamically allocated object

Tags: c++, c++11, initialization

This one might be trivial, yet I could not name it properly hence I could not find an answer.

Is there any significant difference between 1 and 2 performance wise?

```
class Object {
  int number_;
  Object(int number) : number_(number) {}
};

// then, in main.

Object* objPtr1 = new Object(11) // nr.1
Object* objPtr2 {new Object{11}} // nr.2
```

From my understanding the only upside of 2 is that `objPtr2` is directly initialized with the address of dynamically created object,
so **no copying** involved.

On the other hand `objPtr1` is being copy initialized, which means that:

1. operator `new` returns an address of newly created object,
2. the address is being copied to `objPtr1`.

This process involves unnecessary copying, which could be omitted by directly initializing (as in 2). If my understanding is correct, does it make much difference performance wise, to use 2 over 1?

Comment: You'll find that they do exactly the same thing in this case: https://godbolt.org/z/n7vcnE

Comment: Thank You for answering @Ted. You made me realise that I could have found out the answer myself in minutes. At least now I will know what tools to use when I bump on similar problem, cheers!

Comment: Both pointers are initialised in the same way, by copying the address returned from `new`. So, yes there is copying involved, but only of pointers which is considered to be trivial here.